# Strict comparison of DateTime Objects

Tags: php, datetime, object, comparison-operators

I am doing a strict comparison on a list of objects, just to identify objects which might have changed, like:

```
if ($oldValue !== $newValue)
```

in some cases `$oldValue` and `$newValue` are `DateTime` objects.

Debugging my app I am getting the following output for my two values just before comparing them:

> DateTime Object
>   (
>       [date] => 2017-04-24 00:00:00.000000
>       [timezone_type] => 3
>       [timezone] => UTC
>   )
>
> DateTime Object
>   (
>       [date] => 2017-04-24 00:00:00.000000
>       [timezone_type] => 3
>       [timezone] => UTC
>   )

Why is my comparison/condition still true?

Comment: Check this article: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When comparing objects in PHP, the `===` operator does not compare values. [It compares instances](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php). This means unless both objects point to the same object, they are not strictly equal.

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared
>   in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they
>   have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and
>   are instances of the same class.
>
> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical
>   if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

Comment: Thanks, will accept the answer. That means in a case, where I want to avoid equality of `"1"` and `1.0` (`==`) but equality of my example objects (`===`) I need to check for types before I can compare my values?

Comment: That would be correct. Or, change the values to be unix timestamps and then do a strict comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know the types upfront and didn't want to take care (which is necessary in your proposal, too). But I understand now I need to.

Comment: Anonymous classes note: comparing 2 identical anonymous class object instances with `==` will always result in `false` since each instance of anonymous class is technically of a different class.